# How to consolidate multiple versions of a download page into one?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, download

I currently am building a bulk download page for my application, and am running into some problems designing the predictability of the main workflow for an end user.

From this screen below (which serves as an example), the goal is to allow a user to either download one file or multiple files at once. The way this system is currently being implemented is that depending on whether users select one or multiple, they are redirected to a different version of the download page.

[image: List view of all files]

Within the download page, a user can select a variety of file formats. The image below shows the page a user will land on when downloading multiple files, which runs them through a variety of options before zipping the file. To add to the complexity, within each file, there can be several subfiles, so downloading an individual will not guarantee that you will end up on the same page as just downloading a simple file.

[image: Bulk Download Files Page]

For files that are simple and can allow a user to download them immediately, that view looks a little different (shown below), and I want to retain that same functionality of allowing them to download without zipping each file format in a different folder.

[image: Individual File Download]

The main problem with these two flows is that a user never knows exactly which version of the download page they will end up on due to the complexity of each file.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reiterate enough, "who will use this, why would they use this and how are they going to use this," if you can state your user case then the functionality should flow from it. The above doesn't logically sit in any user case that I can derive from it, the 'statement' appearance of the top screen appears at odds with the PNG and raster formats being offered below.

Comment: I don't understand the point of having multiple selection stages. Why not just use the batch interface? The user can download a single file by selecting only one file. The backend can determine without any user intervention whether anything needs to be "zipped".

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why do you need a separate flow for a single file vs many? Save the user a click? They'll have to learn two different pages instead of just 1.

Comment: @Bowen it's because there are two possible use cases. A user will want to download images individually in different formats, which can performed immediately. The other use case is that they want it in a variety of formats for several files, which could take a while for the system to zip and then allow a user to download the zip file. If we let an individual download 30 files at one time, it might slow down their browser or be too taxing cognitively.

Comment: @DarrylGodden you bring up a good point. I've abstracted out this use case a bit due to confidentiality issues, but the use case exists for both. Users need the ability to download files in a variety of ways, due to that being our primary reason why people use our application in the first place.

Comment: @xiota The example I outlined above is oversimplified. What would happen if a single "file" also had many subfiles associated with it? How would you indicate to the user which page they're going to land on just from the table/list screen?

Comment: "I've abstracted out this use case a bit..." – Your approach is either unnecessarily complicated or the use cases are far outside of most people's experiences. Consider uploading *real* screenshots of your app with sensitive information hidden.

Comment: What is the difference between the user (1) selecting checkboxes for JPEG, PNG, PDF and confirming download, vs (2) clicking download JPEG, download PNG, download PDF? Wouldn't the result be the same? (Having each of those files downloaded).

Comment: Also, how complex can the files get? Are we talking about a multiple level folder tree structure like Google Drive? If someone wanted to download an entire folder, will they have to determine the formats they want for each of the children files?

Comment: @NicolasHung difference is that some files can be instantly downloaded because they are simple enough and can be asynchronous started by the browser and communicate with the remote server. Other files (folders, according to your analogy), could potentially be hundreds of megabytes large, and need to be zipped because it doesn't make sense for them to be downloaded instantly. Instead, a user can view the progress of those zipped files in a separate section of the app or get an email notification when that download is ready.

Comment: @NicolasHung - to answer your second question, no. Formats only need to be chosen once and will apply to all files within that folder. In that analogy, the example is that you might want to download a single image in Google Drive in a variety of formats, whereas a folder containing only images might need to be bulk-downloaded (zipped) in several formats. There's a total of perhaps 50 different formats across three different categories.

Appreciate the help, by the way!

Comment: What is the value of showing the user which page will load before clicking? IS the value in knowing what download interface will load? Or is the value in knowing whether a listing represents a single file vs multiple? If the the latter, I think introducing a simple icon (e.g. stacked documents) coupled with a description (50 files) would do the trick. Furthermore, I think there are some opportunities to consolidate the download pages so they don't look so different. Lastly, will users want to download 1 file out of a folder with 50 files?

Comment: @NicolasHung Great points. The value is being more predictable - for a new user coming to the system, there's currently no indication of which page they will land on when downloading an individual file - either the individual or bulk page. Consolidate the pages to make them look similar is something I've done. The icon is a good idea - we'll try to incorporate that in the list page.

Users will want to download one file out of a folder, but there's an individual file view page that tackles some of that functionality, so we don't need to include it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least some suggestions...

Some questions I have are:

After I make some file selections, will I remember what they are and what formats I will need to select for each file as I'm using the download screens? Will it be easy to go back and check? How many files am I likely to download at one time?

1. Would it be possible to reveal, for example, a select box when I check a file that provides my available file format options in the current table? The selection could take place before the download screen.
2. Maybe instead of a checkbox, when I click on a file it directly shows me the format options, where my selection is then added to que/form, and I am returned to the main file list page. Then the download action aggregates all these selections as review. Your "simple" file screen could be an overlay, for example, that "confirms" the file should be checked when a format is selected.

Both of these would try to get the user to select the file format concurrently with the file selection.

I keep thinking, I would feel better knowing the files I want are already selected before I step into the next stage of the workflow. (For single files your second example is perfect, for multiple files it does change a bit)

This could help provide a more consistent second-step (download) screen. Would make coding in the backend easier too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take a step back and decide which formats are to be downloaded for a file when you are viewing details of that file before adding them to the download queue. If the image in the question is a download file list, then it should also display what formats have been selected for each file and the corresponding sizes. You can also zip the files before adding them to the list, if they are to be downloaded separately.